# Add only some IDs to MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I got the following code and like to add a part, which controls which IDS should be shown. 
Each row has an ID, and i would like to enter for example the ID 3,4 and 7 to show up. Any ideas how i can do this? Thanks a lot!

```
    $itemsStmt = $pdo->query(
    'SELECT '
    .     '*, '
    .     'COUNT(v.voting_weight) AS cStimmen '
    . 'FROM abl_gewinnspiel g '
    . 'LEFT OUTER JOIN votes v '
    . 'ON '
    .     'v.vote_item_id = g.ID '
    . 'GROUP BY g.ID '
    . 'ORDER BY cStimmen DESC');
$voteItems = $itemsStmt->fetchAll();
```

Thought about . 'WHERE ID = (23,45,56)', But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

use `IN`

```
WHERE ID IN (23,45,56)
```

or the longer one, `OR`

```
WHERE ID = 23 OR ID = 45 OR ID = 56
```

Comment: Just gives me this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in